# Update Amazon S3 file hourly

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to update the date of a file hourly using Lambda to update a file modified date in Amazon S3.

This code works for me

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new AWS.S3();

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    await s3.putObject({
        Bucket: 'BUCKET_NAME',
        Key: 'KEY_NAME',
        Body: 'content',
    }).promise();
    console.log("file updated in s3 at http://s3://BUCKET_NAME/KEY_NAME")
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify("file updated in s3 at http://s3://BUCKET_NAME/KEY_NAME"),
    };
    return response;
};
```

but I want to keep the content of the original file and can't insert it into the Body line.

Thanks

Comment: Unless you are willing to delete and recreate the object (also changing the creation date) - this can't be done.

Comment: Please clarify: You want to change the `Last-Modified` date of an object in S3 *without* actually changing its contents?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It seems like an unusual solution. If you share the underlying requirement, maybe we can help you find a better solution.

Comment: I have a JSON file for Alexa Skill briefing and need that files date/time to update every hour. Is there a better way of updating just the JSON Date and Time hourly using only Amazon Lambda + CloudWatch @jarmod

Comment: _Why_ does it need to update every hour? Can you provide a reference?

Answer (score 1):

You can `copy_object()` to itself. This will copy the contents and will update the `LastModified`.

Comment: Remember to specify [`MetadataDirective='COPY'`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.copy_object) among the options, to preserve the rest of the object's metadata.  Last-Modified will still be updated.